# Update method of ViewModel class is not working

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room, viewmodel

I am making this basic Notes App named Scribble
I wrote ViewModel class and all of its methods that is insert and delete are working fine but for some reason update method is not working, Its just not updating the passed note object
Please find code below :

First of all this is my Note i.e. Entity Class :

```
@Entity(tableName = "NotesTable")
data class Note constructor(

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") var noteTitle: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") var noteDescription: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timeStamp") var timeStamp: String

):java.io.Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id : Int = 0
}
```

NoteViewModel Class :

```
class NoteViewModel (application: Application) : AndroidViewModel (application){

 val allNotes: LiveData<List<Note>>
 val repository: NoteRepository

init {

    val dao = NoteDatabase.getDatabase(application).getNotesDao()

    repository = NoteRepository(dao)

    allNotes = repository.allNotes
}


fun insertNote(note: Note) {

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){

        repository.insertNote(note)
    }
}


fun deleteNote(note: Note) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){repository.deleteNote(note)}

fun updateNote(note: Note) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){repository.updateNote(note)}
```

Repository class :

```
class NoteRepository (private val noteDao: NoteDao) {

val allNotes : LiveData<List<Note>> = noteDao.getAllNotes()

suspend fun insertNote(note : Note){
    noteDao.insert(note)
}

suspend fun deleteNote(note : Note){
    noteDao.delete(note)
}

suspend fun updateNote(note : Note){
    noteDao.update(note)
}
```

DAO class :

```
@Dao 
public interface NoteDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)

 fun insert(note: Note)

@Update
 fun update(note: Note)

@Delete
 fun delete(note: Note)

@Query("Select * from NotesTable order by id ASC")
 fun getAllNotes() : LiveData<List<Note>>
```

Now this is my EditNote Activity on which I come after clicking on a note card in my recycler view I am saving note when user presses back button after editing the note thus called updateNote method inside onDestroy :

```
class EditNoteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var titleOfNote : EditText
lateinit var bodyOfNote : EditText
lateinit var noteToUpdate: Note
lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_note)

    noteViewModel  = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application))[NoteViewModel::class.java]

    titleOfNote = findViewById(R.id.titleEt)
    bodyOfNote = findViewById(R.id.bodyEt)

    noteToUpdate = intent.getSerializableExtra("noteObject") as Note

    titleOfNote.setText(noteToUpdate.noteTitle)
    bodyOfNote.setText(noteToUpdate.noteDescription)
}

fun updateNote(){
    Log.d("AppLogs", "updateNote: called")
    noteToUpdate.noteTitle = titleOfNote.text.toString()
    noteToUpdate.noteDescription = bodyOfNote.text.toString()
    val current = LocalDateTime.now()
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy \nHH:mm")
    noteToUpdate.timeStamp  = current.format(formatter)
    noteViewModel.updateNote(noteToUpdate)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.d("AppLogs", "onDestroy(updateNote): called")
    updateNote()
}
```

I've used literally the same logic in AddNoteActivity and it works, it saves my note when i press back button and recycler view shows it perfectly

AddNoteActivity class :

```
class AddNoteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var noteTitle : EditText
lateinit var noteBody : EditText
lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note)

    noteTitle = findViewById(R.id.noteTitleEt)
    noteBody = findViewById(R.id.noteBodyEt)

    noteViewModel  = ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application))[NoteViewModel::class.java]

}

fun saveNote(){
    Log.d("AppLogs", "saveNote: called")
    var titleOfNote : String = noteTitle.text.toString()
    var bodyOfNote : String = noteBody.text.toString()
    val current = LocalDateTime.now()

    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy \nHH:mm")
    val timeStamp = current.format(formatter)
    var note = Note(titleOfNote,bodyOfNote,timeStamp)
    noteViewModel.insertNote(note)

}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    Log.d("AppLogs", "onStop: called !")
    saveNote()
}
```

}

means insertNote method from NoteViewModel works fine, similarly deleteNote also works fine, it deletes the note when I press delete button its just something wrong with updateNote method that I am not able to figure out

OTHER CLASSES ::::

NoteViewAdapter Class :

```
class NoteViewAdapter( allNotes : List<Note>, context: Context,  clickListeners: ClickListeners)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteViewAdapter.NoteViewHolder>() {

private val clickListeners : ClickListeners
private val context : Context
private var allNotes : List<Note>

init {
    this.clickListeners = clickListeners
    this.context = context
    this.allNotes = allNotes
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int)
: NoteViewAdapter.NoteViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.note_row,parent,false)
    return NoteViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.noteTitleTV.text = allNotes[position].noteTitle
    holder.noteBodyTV.text = allNotes[position].noteDescription
    holder.timeStampTV.text = allNotes[position].timeStamp

    holder.deleteButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
        clickListeners.onDeleteButtonClick(allNotes[position])
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
        clickListeners.onNoteClick(allNotes[position])
    }
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener{
        holder.deleteButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val timer = Timer("schedule", true);
        timer.schedule(2000) {
            holder.deleteButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        return@setOnLongClickListener true
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return allNotes.size
}

inner class NoteViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

     val noteTitleTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTV)
     val noteBodyTV: TextView  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bodyTV)
     val deleteButton: FloatingActionButton  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton)
     val timeStampTV : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeStamp)

}
```

}

interface ClickListeners {
fun onNoteClick(note: Note)
fun onDeleteButtonClick(note: Note)
}

MainActivity class :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ClickListeners {

lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView
lateinit var addButton : FloatingActionButton
lateinit var viewModel : NoteViewModel
lateinit var adapter : NoteViewAdapter


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.NotesRV)
    addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton)
    viewModel  = ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application))[NoteViewModel::class.java]
    viewModel.allNotes.observe(this, Observer {list ->
        adapter = NoteViewAdapter(list ,this, this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    })

    recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)

    addButton.setOnClickListener{
         val intent : Intent = Intent(this,AddNoteActivity::class.java)
         startActivity(intent)
    }

}

override fun onNoteClick(note: Note) {
    val intent : Intent = Intent(this,EditNoteActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("noteObject",note)
    startActivity(intent)
}

override fun onDeleteButtonClick(note: Note) {
    viewModel.deleteNote(note)
}
```

Here I am passing note object with intent Extras because I implemented java.io.Serializable in Note class

When I click on note it opens edit note activity then I change the previous text set there, but when i press back button it doesnt update note
I used debug logs and found that both onDestroy and updateNote are getting called but still it is note updating my note
Also these lines from EditNoteActivity.kt are setting previous entered text in note after clicking on note card

`titleOfNote.setText(noteToUpdate.noteTitle)`
`bodyOfNote.setText(noteToUpdate.noteDescription)`

but for some reason this line isn't working

`noteViewModel.updateNote(noteToUpdate)`

Comment: Check to be sure `noteToUpdate` has the proper ID and not 0 at the moment you call `updateNote()`. It seems suspicious to me that `id` is not part of the data class constructor (therefore not participating in `copy()` or `equals()`), and that you're relying on Serializable instead of the more robust Parcelable.

Comment: In your Activity where it works, you're doing the saving in `onStop` - in the one where it *doesn't* you're saving in `onDestroy`. Because the `ViewModel`'s lifecycle ends when the Activity is *finished* (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle) that means the `ViewModelScope` you're launching those update coroutines in might get cancelled before they have a chance to run. I don't know for sure, but I'd check there first

Comment: @cactustictacs oh my god I literally knew this that's why I used onStop() in add note activity I don't know what made me use onDestroy() in edit note activity Thank you so much for pointing this out.

Comment: @vibhummohan no worries! If I were you I'd add some comments in both of those `onStop()`s, pointing out why it's there and what you need to watch out for - just to help future you (or whoever)